# How to use the audio created by pyttsx3 in the microphone output or choose audio output driver?

Tags: python, audio, microphone, pyttsx3

Usage need:

I'm going to do a draw during an audio conference, for that I'm generating a random number in Python and making `pyttsx3` read the text created.

```
from num2words import num2words
from random import randint
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('voice','HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\MSTTS_V110_ptBR_DanielM')

text = num2words(randint(1,10), lang='pt_BR')
engine.say(text=f'The number drawn was {text}')
engine.runAndWait()
```

But this speech is coming out of my speaker, I would like this speech to come out as my microphone, so that people who are in the conference call hear the result of the draw as if I were speaking.

If `Visual Studio Code` or `Python` appears in the Windows sound apps list, I could set the output to `CABLE Input` and use it as a microphone on my digital soundboard as I did with `Google Chrome`:

[image]

But as they do not appear, I would like to know if there is any way to select which audio output driver `pyttsx3` will use or if there is some other module that can work with it to make this choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to play the speech audio generated by pyttsx3 using pygame module and an external software, VB-CABLE.

Just install VB-CABLE (https://vb-audio.com/Cable/) and install the pygame module.

```
pip install pygame
```

Here is a sample code:

```
import pyttsx3
from pygame import mixer, _sdl2 as devices

# Get available output devices
mixer.init()
print("Outputs:", devices.audio.get_audio_device_names(False))
mixer.quit()

# Initialize mixer with the correct device
# Set the parameter devicename to use the VB-CABLE name from the outputs printed previously.
mixer.init(devicename = "CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)")

# Initialize text to speech
engine = pyttsx3.Engine()
text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

# Save speech as audio file
engine.save_to_file(text, "speech.wav")
engine.runAndWait()

# Play the saved audio file
mixer.music.load("speech.wav")
mixer.music.play()
```

Don't forget to delete the audio files created afterwards.